# Reading fuse mount and filesystem stats

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

I have an `sshfs.fuse` mount. I am looking for a way to read mount statistics, e.g. bytes read/written, something similar to what `/proc/diskstats` contains for disk devices. `fusermount` has nothing to get statistics. There doesn't seem to be anything useful in `/proc` or `/dev`.

This is not for interactive monitoring. I need it for automation.

I would appreciate if anyone shared experience/knowledge regarding where to look for this information

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you monitoring network for this, so from server where is unit mounted you can monitoring traffic for that disk.

Also, if you need know bytes writen to your remote disk, you will need check /proc/diskstats in your remote server when physical disk is.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from: do you wish a tool or you need know what 'pseudo filesystem' data [to look at](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/iostats.html) (like `/proc`)?

As about linux tools I'm not sure is there any problem, especially when everything in Linux is file. Install `sysstat` & `iotop` for example.

- To get an overview of disk I/O activity: `iostat -d`. Or get an overview for `sda` block device: `iostat -d -p loop1` (or `/dev/loop1` where mountpoint was taken from `losetup -a`).
- `iotop` command displays a view of disk I/O by each process or thread: `iotop -o`.
- Report activity for each block device using sar: `sar -p -d -b 1`.
- Look at the disk statistics with vmstat: `vmstat -d 1`.
- Monitor a process which writes to file (something like `lsof + grep`), where backing file of loop device was taken from `losetup --list --noheadings -O BACK-FILE /dev/loop0` command output (check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144425/source-path-of-loop-device)).

I believe one of them could work for you. Also please check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io).